# Nuget reversion a package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm a creating a NuGet Package every time I build my project.

Versioning is like,

1.0.0-Build1
1.0.0-Build2
1.0.0-Build3...

But once after I get the signoff for a package I need to re-version same to 1.0.0-Beta*.

For example, if I get the singoff for 1.0.0-Build3, I want to re-version the package as 1.0.0-Beta3.

**I have the Package and I want re-pack it with a different version. How to do that. Please advise.**

Comment: I don't use nuget but it seems to me you don't actually have a question in your question.  You might want to change that.

Comment: Highlighted my question